# File upload in JSF using PrimeFaces 5.1

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

When I put this code, the validation is working for all the other field except room-image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Colonial Inn</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.PNG" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
        <div>
            <ui:include src="adminheader.xhtml" />
        </div>

        <p:outputPanel>
            <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
                <div class="ui-grid-row">
                    <h:form id="loginForm">
                        <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                        </div>

                        <div class="ui-grid-col-2">
                            <h:panelGrid id="loginPanel">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Room Number" />
                                <p:inputText id="roomnumber" value="#{addroom.roomnumber}"
                                             required="true" maxlength="4">
                                    <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" />
                                </p:inputText>

                                <p:spacer></p:spacer>

                                <p:message for="roomnumber"></p:message>

                                <p:outputLabel value="Room Name " />
                                <p:inputText id="roomname" value="#{addroom.roomname}"
                                             required="true">
                                </p:inputText>

                                <p:spacer></p:spacer>

                                <p:message for="roomname"></p:message>

                                <p:outputLabel value="Room Details"></p:outputLabel>
                                <p:inputTextarea id="roomdetails" value="#{addroom.roomdetails}"
                                                 required="true"></p:inputTextarea>
                                <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                                <p:message for="roomdetails"></p:message>

                                <p:outputLabel value="Upload Room Image"></p:outputLabel>
                                <p:fileUpload id="roomimage" value="#{addroom.roomimage}"
                                              mode="simple" skinSimple="true" required="true">
                                </p:fileUpload>

                                <p:spacer></p:spacer>

                                <p:message for="roomimage"></p:message>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Room Type"></p:outputLabel>

                                <p:selectOneListbox id="roomtype" value="#{addroom.roomtype}"
                                                    required="true">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="single" itemValue="single" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="double" itemValue="double" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="other" itemValue="other" />
                                </p:selectOneListbox>

                                <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                                <p:message for="roomtype"></p:message>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </div>

                        <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                        </div>

                        <div class="ui-grid-col-2">
                            <h:panelGrid id="loginPanel1">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Smoking" />

                                <p:selectOneListbox id="smoke" value="#{addroom.smoke}"
                                                    required="true">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Smoking" itemValue="Smoking" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="NonSmoking" itemValue="NonSmoking" />
                                </p:selectOneListbox>

                                <p:spacer></p:spacer>

                                <p:message for="smoke"></p:message>

                                <p:outputLabel value="Pets Allowed" />
                                <p:selectOneListbox id="pets" value="#{addroom.pets}"
                                                    required="true">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No" />
                                </p:selectOneListbox>

                                <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                                <p:message for="pets"></p:message>

                                <p:outputLabel value="Rent/day"></p:outputLabel>
                                <p:inputText id="rent" value="#{addroom.rent}" required="true"></p:inputText>
                                <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                                <p:message for="rent"></p:message>

                                <p:outputLabel value="Properties"></p:outputLabel>
                                <p:selectManyCheckbox id="properties"
                                                      value="#{addroom.selectedproperty}" layout="grid" columns="1"
                                                      required="true">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{addroom.property}" var="prop"
                                                   itemLabel="#{prop}" itemValue="#{prop}" />
                                </p:selectManyCheckbox>

                                <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                                <p:message for="properties"></p:message>
                            </h:panelGrid>

                            <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{addroom.add}"
                                             style="margin-top:30px;width:auto; background-color:#4cc1d2;">
                            </h:commandButton>
                        </div>
                    </h:form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </p:outputPanel>

        <div style="height: auto; bottom: 0%; width: 100%; opacity: 1;">
            <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

When I add enctype in  then it stop validating the other filed also including roomimage.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="loginForm">
```

So, how can I invoke the validation also even the `<h:form>` tag contain `enctype`?